# Rows are not equal sizes in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and trying to have columns which are the same height (which I thought Bootstrap did by default).

This is my markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="table-heading">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="table-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="table-heading">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    </div>
    <div class="table-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="table-heading">
        Lorem ipsum dolor
    </div>
    <div class="table-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

I'd like the purple headings to align, as well as the columns themselves.

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.table-heading {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color:white;
    background-color: #7b2265;
    padding:10px;
}

.table-text {
    padding:10px;
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Here's a Pen:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxeLpO

Comment: That class was removed in the BS4 betas as it is on by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit:

Since you want **both, the titles AND the body text parts** to be the same height while **also making sure that they are responsive**, you can use the re-ordering classes in combination with the `h-100` class (height:100%) to achieve the desired effect:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<style>
    .table-heading {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color:white;
        background-color: #7b2265;
        padding:10px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container bg-light p-3">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="table-heading h-100">
              Title1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 order-md-1">
          <div class="bg-white h-100 px-3">
              Body1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
          </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="table-heading h-100">
              Title2 Long, long, veeery long! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2">
          <div class="bg-white h-100 px-3">
              Body2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore. Body2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore. 
          </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="table-heading h-100">
              Title3 Short Lorem
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 order-md-3">
          <div class="bg-white h-100 px-3">
              Body3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
          </div>
      </div>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

The classes like `order-md-1` etc. only kick in on screens that are medium (`md`) or larger. In this case here, it has the effect of the body part columns being pushed what looks like the next row. While on smaller screens, no re-ordering happens and therefore, on smaller screens, the columns appear in the same order as they are in the HTML.

Comment: Click the "run code snippet" in my answer. It works perfectly when I post it.

Comment: Of course not. Because your custom css is messing up Bootstrap that's why. You should use the native Bootstrap classes to get the job done.

Comment: I'm not sure which custom css is messing it up.  If I take out everything except the background colours, it still doesn't work... ?

Comment: I see I can take out the background color and add it to the col-md instead - but I still have the problem of the titles not being the same height

Comment: Aha! Now you are talking about titles! Well, in this case, an adjustment is needed...

Comment: So, the titles also need to be all the same height, correct?

Comment: OK. So, question answered then?

Comment: Setting the height to 80px doesn't work when you move the layout to mobile - the title may then go over 3 rows and be cut off (I don't need the titles or rows to be the same height on mobile)

Comment: Just updated my answer. A little trick was needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `h-100` as a class to the divs with `col-md-4` as a class then it will behave as you expect.

`h-100` is the bootstrap4 utility class to set the height to 100%, which will make all the columns have a height equal to the row they all reside in.

```
<div class="col-md-4 h-100">
    ...
</div>
```

Update, you can add `height: 100%` to the css class `.table-text` to fill the empty space.

Comment: DIdn't help unfortunately, same result

Comment: Try adding the `height: 100%` to `.table-text` or the class `h-100` to the div with that class containing the `table-text`. (It works on the code-pen as well)